# load more scroll based on div height

Tags: javascript, css

Load more/infinite scroll button that is based on the div height. Lets say I have a div at 500px in height and the content inside the div is equal to 1000px. How would I load only 500px of the div and with a button load the remaining 500px of the div on click?

I hope this is clear?

Comment: the way html is structured will make it very hard to do by height. you're better off segmenting the content into separate pieces and then loading them with a lazy-loader like http://jscroll.com/

Comment: set height:500px and overflow: hidden to the div and when click the load button, use javascript to change the height

Comment: Please show where your code is at, and what you were doing when your scroll loading broke.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with javascript and css

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/tnTPw/2/

```
$('.div').click(function () {
                $(this).addClass('height');

            });
```